# Sql Server 2008 Database Keeps Growing Larger Than It Should Be

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been researching this for a long time. I have a ASPDOTNETSTOREFRONT store. We also currently have a 500 meg database cap. Every month the database grows about 200megs. I have been told to Null out some data that is not needed unless you have problems. Microsoft came up with the below.

```
Update customer set RTShipResponse = NULL where RTShipResponse is not null
Update customer set RTShipRequest = NULL where RTShipRequest is not null
Update customer set referrer = NULL where referrer is not null

Update orders set RTShipRequest = NULL where RTShipRequest is not null
Update orders set RTShipResponse = NULL where RTShipResponse is not null
Update orders set referrer = NULL where referrer is not null
```

Before I ran the above scrip the database total was saying  450 megs total. After I ran it, it jumped to 730 megs. After I have shrunk it with 3% space ended up with 435 megs. Why can’t I recover all the space I have deleted? Saturday I deleted about 175 megs total and a small fraction was given back.

The largest Table size is 220 megs If you add up the column data total it's under 50 megs. It seems that the largest tables are the ones I keep running the scrip above. Running database shrink does not release any more space.

Last year the database was 700 megs, my host backed-up the DB and restored it on another server using a different name. Once restored, it showed 500 megs of free space. Ran a DB shrink and got it all back.

I hope I entered enough data, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Rebuild the tables to reclaim freed space in them.

```
ALTER TABLE customer REBUILD;
ALTER TABLE orders REBUILD;
etc.
```

After that you'll be able to shrink the database with `DBCC SHRINKDATABASE`.

Comment: Ok I ran the above alter table's, It recovered about 1-2 megs. I'm weak to SQL server. I tried to run DBCC SHRINKDATABASE it returned        Msg 2583, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
An incorrect number of parameters was given to the DBCC statement.

Comment: I did run database shrink through the GUI. Same effect

Answer (score 0):

Within ASPDNSF it is usually the profile.dbo that grows and causes this issue. The profile.dbo adds a line whenever someone changes page within the database. Are you running your monthly maintenence from within the admin section? This should clean the profile table as part of this. However, depending on the version there is a known bug that can stop this running.

Use this code to see the size of your tables

```
DECLARE @table table(Id int IDENTITY(1,1)
                , Name varchar(256))

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT b.name + '.'+ a.name
FROM sys.tables a INNER JOIN sys.schemas b
    ON a.schema_id = b.schema_id

INSERT INTO @table
SELECT '-1'

DECLARE @result table(  TableName varchar(256)
                    , TotalRows int
                    , Reserved varchar(50)
                    , DataSize varchar(50)
                    , IndexSize varchar(50)
                    , UnusedSize varchar(50))

DECLARE @temp varchar(256)
DECLARE @index int
SET @index = 1

WHILE 1=1
BEGIN
SELECT @temp = Name
FROM @table
WHERE Id = @index

IF @temp = '-1'
    BREAK       

INSERT @result( TableName
                , TotalRows
                , Reserved
                , DataSize
                , IndexSize
                , UnusedSize)
EXEC sp_spaceused @temp

SET @index = @index + 1
END

SELECT c.name+'.'+b.name as [table]
    , a.*
FROM @result a
    INNER JOIN sys.tables b
        ON a.TableName = b.name
    INNER JOIN sys.schemas c
    ON b.schema_id = c.schema_id
ORDER BY TotalRows DESC
```

Usually this will clear the profile table

```
 delete top(50000) from dbo.Profile  where UpdatedOn < '2014-05-01'
 delete top(50000) from dbo.Profile  where UpdatedOn < '2014-05-01'
 delete top(50000) from dbo.Profile  where UpdatedOn < '2014-05-01'
 delete top(50000) from dbo.Profile  where UpdatedOn < '2014-05-01'
 delete top(50000) from dbo.Profile  where UpdatedOn < '2015-05-01'
```

You can change this to what you like. The individual SQL that runs each part of the monthly maint is within the Stored Procedure dbo.aspdnsf_MonthlyMaintenence

Our profile table was once 95gig!

Comment: I do run monthly maintenance. I may have the version with the bug. ASPDNSF gave the following for the profile query and it runs and shrinks down ok.         DELETE dbo.Profile WHERE UpdatedOn < dateadd(d,-7,getdate())    When I run the above quary I get the following error.  Msg 1087, Level 15, State 2, Line 15
Must declare the table variable "@table".  Tanks for your help so far.

Comment: make sure that you have your database selected or try adding USE yourdatabasename at the beginning of the SQL and GO at the end. Ps the SQL script above will only remove the last 7 days of profile views. You can change the -7 to how many days you want